# How to sort in ascending or descending by a column all my rows of a CSV file in C#. Without using Function Split

Tags: c#, sorting, csv

My file have their columns by Number ID, Name and Salary. which i need sort by the salary.

```
        2,Sam,500.00
        6,Mike,400.00
        8,Robert,156.00
        3,Steve,100.85
        9,Anderson,234.90
```

My Code Read the Data from the CSV File like this way...

```
        List<string[]> fileContent = new List<string[]>();

        using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"C:\File.csv"))

        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
        {
            parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
            parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
            parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] line = parser.ReadFields();

                foreach (string fieldRowCell in line)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fieldRowCell);

                    fileContent.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

and last I need to write a file with the data Ordered

```
     File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Result.csv", fieldRowCell);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract value anyway. If you do not want use Split, it's not very useful since in this case can consume memory when it's not necessary, you can g through row and count amount of comma to get value you need. For this purpose I use extenssion method IndexOfNth in my example and then just find index and length which allows to extract value from row by using Substring.

In example data is sorted by column Name, index of column is 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class StringExtenssion 
{
    public static int IndexOfNth(this string input, string value, int startIndex, int nth)
    {
        if (nth < 1)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Param 'nth' must be greater than 0!");
        if (nth == 1)
            return input.IndexOf(value, startIndex);
        var idx = input.IndexOf(value, startIndex);
        if (idx == -1)
            return -1;
        return input.IndexOfNth(value, idx + 1, --nth);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static string GetColumnDataValue(string row, int column)
    {
        int startIndex = 0;
        int length = row.Length;
        if (column != 0)
            startIndex = row.IndexOfNth(",", 0, column) + 1;

        var indexOfNextComma = row.IndexOf(",", startIndex);
        if (indexOfNextComma == -1)
            length = row.Length - startIndex - 1;
        else
            length = indexOfNextComma - startIndex;

        return row.Substring(startIndex, length);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {       
        List<string> list = new List<string> {
            "2,Sam,500.00",
            "6,Mike,400.00",
            "8,Robert,156.00",
            "3,Steve,100.85",
            "9,Anderson,234.90",
        };

        var sortBy = 1;

        list.Sort((a,b) => GetColumnDataValue(a, sortBy).CompareTo(GetColumnDataValue(b, sortBy)));
        foreach(var row in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/2xohN8

Answer (score 0):

To perform sorting you must get column value. You cannot get column value without splitting your rowData by comma.

Main solution:

```
public class Row
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}

    public Row(string rowStr)
    {
        string[] cols = rowStr.Split(',');
        Id = int.Parse(cols[0]);
        Name = cols[1];
        Value = double.Parse(cols[2]);
    }

    public string AsString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", Id, Name, Value);
    }
}


List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();
using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"C:\File.csv"))
{
    string rowStr = reader.ReadLine(); 
    rows.Add(new Row(rowStr));  
}

rows = rows.OrderBy(r=>r.Id);
rows = rows.OrderByDescending(r=>r.Name);

foreach(Row row in rows)
{
   outputFile.WriteLine(row.AsString);
}
```

Another way:

```
public class RowComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private int _columnIndex;

    public RowComparer(int columnIndex)
    {
        _columnIndex = columnIndex;

    }
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        string valA = a.Split(',')[columnIndex];
        string valB = b.Split(',')[columnIndex];
        if(valA == valB) return 0;

        return valA >  valB ? 1 : -1;

    }
}

List<string> rows = GetAllLinesFromFile();

// sort ascending by column index 2 (Value)
rows = rows.OrderBy(r=> r, new RowComparer(2));

// sort descending by column index 1 (Name)
rows = rows.OrderByDescending(r=> r, new RowComparer(1));
```